# Is there a pandas function that can create a dataframe of the mean, median, and mode of selected columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, statistics

My attempt:

```
# Compute the mean, median and variance for the variables sph, acous and dur. Compare their level of variability.
sad_mean = dat_songs[['spch', 'acous', 'dur']].mean()
sad_mode = dat_songs[['spch', 'acous', 'dur']].mode()
sad_median = dat_songs[['spch', 'acous', 'dur']].median()

sad_mmm = pd.DataFrame({'mean':sad_mean, 'median':sad_median, 'mode':sad_mode})
sad_mmm
```

[Which outputs this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2d4G.png)

First of all, the median column is not right at all and want to know how to fix that too.
Secondly, I feel like I have seen some quicker or shorter way to do this with a simple function with pandas.

[My data head for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdSTf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Simply try, `dat_songs.describe()`. Descriptive Statistics will be present for all the numerical columns.
For selected columns.

```
dat_songs[['spch', 'acous', 'dur']].describe()
```